# Inference on Large image using 2Gb gpu in keras

Tags: keras

I want to get inference on 3584x2796 size of 2D image on a 2 Gb GPU using Keras. Is it possible? network architecture is an Unet.

The out of memory error comes all the time during inference. Even the convolution, only for the first layer fails. It seems Keras is not optimized for large image convolutions. Even the network below fails during inference on a 2 Gb GPU.

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         (None, 3584, 2796, 1)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 3584, 2796, 32)     80        
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 3584, 2796, 32)     584       
_________________________________________________________________
instance_normalization_3 (In (None, 3584, 2796, 32)     2         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 3584, 2796, 32)     0         
=================================================================
Total params: 666
Trainable params: 666
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I get below error:

```
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,32,3584,2796] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node conv2d_2/convolution}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](conv2d_2/convolution-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer, conv2d_2/kernel/read)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

     [[{{node activation_2/Relu/_11}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_47_activation_2/Relu", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

Answer (score 0):

The input image is enormous.

Even 11GB of Video Ram (GTX 1080 Ti for example) is not enough to handle such a size.

2GB GPU is really not enough for deep learning, especially for computer vision.

First of all, please use a GPU with at least 4GB of VRAM. 6GB of VRAM would be a good starting point, 8GB of VRAM would be more suitable.

Second of all, try to reduce the initial image size (3584x2796) to (448x350). Practically you divide both the height and the width by 8.

This is not about Keras optimization, but about the memory size of your GPU and the huge size of the input image.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can not reduce the image size as I need to get the inference on same scale. This is image translation problem. The model is trained using big GPUs, now I am trying to find a way for inference. I can not understand why does it need so much memory, especially for the small model I have attached?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think there is a way to infer on such a GPU. As I have said, try a much bigger video card and with the input image reduced. Such memory allocations are not exclusively dependent upon the number of parameters they you see when you call model.summary(). For example, 138.000.000, that is the number of parameters VGG-19 contains. The input image is of 224x224. That's why I insisted on reducing the image size. The replication can be done only by using very powerful GPUs. You cannot expect to train on 3 GPUs with 8GB VRAM and then the network on 1 GPU with 2GB VRAM.

Comment: An inference is a forward-pass through the neural network. It's just like an image is passed through that neural network, but for prediction instead of training. If you cannot train on that video card with a certain configuration, neither can you test with the same configuration.

Comment: I think, the training requires more memory because of back-propagation. But there might be some ways to optimize a unet during inference, for example using small parts at a time. I understand it is a challenging possible and you are right about using bigger gpus but I do not have that option.

Comment: You are right in that sense, backpropagation requires more memory as  by its means the weights are updated. And yes, you do need a much powerful configuration. You can try to check if you split the initial image into subparts, and send those subparts to the U-Net instead of the whole image. Spatial information may be lost but at least I think it could be an option. Of course, a much better GPU is the solution to this, as well as reduced image size.

Comment: If you have any more doubts, I would be glad to assist :)

Comment: I have tried making image sub patches and passing through the model. The problem is that when I back project patches, every patch looks different in the image. Thanks for good discussion.

Comment: Glad to have helped you clarify some ideas.